# Conditional rendering - show div based on user select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, conditional-rendering

I have a select dropdown and want to use the value to decide if a div is shown via `v-if`.

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" id="lang">
  <option value="1">English</option>
  <option value="2">Svenska</option>
</select>
```

```
<a class="nav-link" v-if="???" href="#">People</a>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: This seems like a Vue specific question - tag added.

Comment: This is a really basic question and while you will be answered shortly probably, I would advise you to read carefully the Vue documentation so you actually learn things. To achieve this you need to familiarise yourself with model binding with v-model and conditional rendering with v-if. After you understand these two things - you will be able to write the code on your own.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You should post what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

This is basic vue functionality as mentioned @Samuil:

```js
new Vue({data:{lang:''}}).$mount('div')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div>
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" id="lang" v-model="lang">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">English</option>
  <option value="2">Svenska</option>
</select>
<a class="nav-link" v-if="lang" href="#">People</a>
</div>
```